# Resolve performance overhead for Oracle order by query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query that fetches over a million of records. With regular select, I dont see any issue and its taking under 1 sec to returns the records.

My requirement is to get top 10 rows after applying order by clause. Its taking around 1 minute to do even after having necessary indexes on tables involved.

Could someone recommend a solution to get top 10 rows after applying sorting?

Comment: Posting the query, the index(es) you've created, and the query plan would be a good first step.  As it is now, no one can guess.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
Select * from (
    /*Your query goes here
    With order by part*/)
where rownum <=10;
```